# Unable to uninstall ubuntu installed using Wubi

Tags: 10.04, wubi

I've installed Ubuntu 10.04 using Wubi from Vista. I'm unable to uninstall it as the uninstall.exe in Ubuntu folder isn't doing anything after double-clicking. Also I checked Add/Remove programs & there is no entry for Wubi/Ubuntu. Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot remove it from Add/Remove programs and the `C:\ubuntu\Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe` file does neither work, you can always do a manual removal.

See [WubiGuide on Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation) for instructions.

Basically, the instructions in your case are:

- Remove `C:\ubuntu` and all files starting with `C:\wubildr`
- Remove the entry from the boot menu: *Control Panel* -> *System* -> *Advanced* -> *Startup and Recovery*, press Edit, select Ubuntu and press Remove.

Comment: I've installed in F:\ubuntu, now since I couldn't uninstall it, I formatted the drive & removed the startup entry. Is that all? Thanks for ur reply.

Comment: @Rahul: that's all according to the wiki page. Wubi installs itself in a directory and adds a boot entry for it. Additionally, an entry may be created at Add/Remove programs.