# How to remove wubi install from windows 7,when I have done a clean install of Windows 8- no dual-boot?

Tags: wubi, windows-7, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to uninstall ubuntu installed using Wubi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40006/unable-to-uninstall-ubuntu-installed-using-wubi)

I had Ubuntu 12.10 intalled using wubi on my windows 7. I then installed Windows 8,and remove Windows 7.
The bootloader and folders on C: drive still exist,and i can't unistall wubi ,as it is'nt installed on Windows 8. Also,i can't install Ubuntu using Wubi on Windows 8 because there is already a folder named 'ubuntu'?

What should I do? Try to delete the files associated with ubuntu??

Comment: Refer to this to remove all the remaining bits: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_manually_uninstall_Wubi.3F